# How to get buffer and sound info for an equalizer using MediaBrowser, MediaController, MediaSession and Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x, android-mediasession

I have an app which can play playlists based on google docs on how to create and Audio App https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app

I would like to add an equalizer, like this one https://github.com/Yalantis/Horizon, but I cannot find how to get the needed information, I have never worked with sound before so I am a bit lost.

According to the docs I should first: "initialize the Horizon object with params referring to your sound:"

```
    mHorizon = Horizon(
        glSurfaceView, ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.grey2),
        RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_ENCODING_BIT //Where to get these 3 constants?
    )
```

And then: "to update Horizon call updateView method with chunk of sound data to proceed:"

```
    val buffer = ByteArray(//Where to get the bytes?)
    mHorizon!!.updateView(buffer)
```

How could I get this data? I looked in the android documentation but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a custom RendererFactory to your Exoplayer to get audio bytes. See the below code:

```
   val rendererFactory = RendererFactory(this, object : TeeAudioProcessor.AudioBufferSink {

            override fun flush(sampleRateHz: Int, channelCount: Int, encoding: Int) {
            }

            override fun handleBuffer(buffer: ByteBuffer) {
                //pass bytes to the your function
            }

        })
   exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, rendererFactory,DefaultTrackSelector())
```

You will get the bytes in a ByteBuffer, To convert it to ByteArray use below code:

```
  try{
    val arr = ByteArray(buffer.remaining())
    buffer[arr] //pass this array to the required function
   }
  catch(exception:Exception)
  {
   // handle exception here
  }
```